# twitter share button and complete url

Tags: php, twitter

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

echo $url; // http://localhost/abcmemento.se/s00/view.php?cat=category-abc&id=1

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $url; ?>" target='_blank'><img class='shareimg' src='social/01.png' alt='img'></a>
```

click on `.shareimg` opens a twitter window containing:

```
http://localhost/abcmemento.se/s00/view.php?cat=category-abc
```

where is `id=1` ?

Comment: You have to `urlencode()` that URL to use it inside the query string of that `href`. Otherwise you end up with an href url that has 2 separate `?` query components.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thanks a lot, solved.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, no, just the answer is the same, not the question.